# R function for creating a new variable based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset loaded into RStudio:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwzz2.png)

I'm trying to create a new variable/ column named "betaplasma_calories_males". The new variable/ column should consist of:

Column Betaplasma + column Calories but only instances for the gender(Sex) Male should be the outputs in the new column.

I've been trying to run the mutate command without success:

`mutate(data, betaplasma_calories_males = data$Betaplasma + data$Calories, data$Sex == 'Male')`

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, add `dput(head(df, 20))` to your question instead of a picture of your data.

Comment: try this : mutate(data, betaplasma_calories_males = ifelse(Sex  == "Male" , Betaplasma + Calories, NA))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It will add values where sex== "Male" and  NA's for other sex values

data <- data %>% mutate( betaplasma_calories_males = ifelse(sex=="Male", Betaplasma + Calories, NA))